# Universal moduli space of rank two vector bundles over a curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, vector-bundles, moduli-spaces

Let $\mathcal M_C$ denote the moduli space of rank two vector bundles over a smooth proper curve $C$ over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic zero.  Let $k(t)$ denote the function field of $\mathbb P^1_k$, and let $\overline{k(t)}$ denote a fixed algebraic closure of $k(t)$.

I would like to consider the direct limit
$$\mathcal M:=\varinjlim_{k(t)\subseteq k(C)\subseteq\overline{k(t)}}\mathcal M_C$$
where the transition maps are the obvious pullback maps $\mathcal M_{C'}\to\mathcal M_C$ associated to maps of curves $C\to C'$ for $k(C')\subseteq k(C)$.  Note that it doesn't matter that we started with $\mathbb P^1_k$; we could just as well have taken the direct limit over $k(C_0)\subseteq k(C)\subseteq\overline{k(C_0)}$ for any fixed curve $C_0/k$ and fixed algebraic closure of its function field, and it would give us the same moduli space $\mathcal M$.

> Has this moduli space $\mathcal M$ been studied before?  Can anything nontrivial/interesting be said about it?

I have been deliberately vague about in which sense I mean "moduli space of rank two vector bundles" (i.e. whether I mean a stack, or the GIT construction, or whether we impose stability conditions on our vector bundles, etc.), because I would be happy with an answer which says something interesting about any of these possible settings.

EDIT: I know a reasonable amount about each individual $\mathcal M_C$, and that others know even more.  The point of this question is to say something nontrivial about the direct limit $\mathcal M$.

EDIT2: I am happy to restrict to bundles of trivial determinant, or, what is almost the same, to consider bundles $E$ and $E\otimes\mathcal L$ to be equivalent for any line bundle $\mathcal L$.

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear,at least put some additional words with more explanation, even for those who can not answer be able to follow your question

Comment: I know that such moduli spaces studied by Narasimhan in 60 and he charactrized them. They are Fano when genus is greater than 1 .May you add some reference or you want to consider quasi-projectivity of them. So certainly it correspond to Lelong number of their canonical metric as Weil-Petersson metric(if you take K-stability notion related to kahler-Einstein metric).

Comment: For every (say, non constant) map $u:C \to C'$ you get a "pullback" morphism $\mathcal{M}_{C'}\to \mathcal{M}_{C}, \; E\mapsto u^* E$. Then you want to form the limit $lim_{\to}\mathcal{M}_C$ w.r.t. the directed set $\{C\to C'\}^{\mathrm{op}}$. Is it correct? In which category are you expecting such a limit to exist?

Comment: @Qfwfq: For the direct limit to be well-behaved, one can't consider simply all curves $C$ and all maps $C\to C'$, rather one needs to "rigidify" things appropriately.  This is the reason for only considering (the smooth proper curves corresponding to) function fields over $k(t)$ contained in a fixed algebraic closure $\overline{k(t)}$.  Now this is a directed set.  The direct limit is pretty trivially an ind-(algebraic stack) over $k$.

Comment: @Qfwfq: Alternatively, one could just regard $\mathcal M_C$ as the *set* of all (isomorphism classes of) vector bundles over $C$ and take the direct limit of that, which obviously exists (since all direct limits exist in the category of sets).  The precise mathematical framework in which one puts the direct limit $\mathcal M$ is less important to me than being able to say something concrete about what $\mathcal M$ looks like.

Comment: To make a silly observation: if every vector bundle of rank two $E/C$ became trivial under some finite map $C'\to C$, that would mean $\mathcal M$ is just a single point.  Of course, this is obviously false, but that's the type of statement I'm looking for.

Comment: "The direct limit is pretty trivially an ind-(algebraic stack)" - Well, it depends on your definition of "ind"; but doesn't the standard definition only involve taking the limit on the totally ordered index set $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: "Of course, this is obviously false" - Is it *so* obvious? https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.5234

Comment: @Qfwfq: The directed set in question has countable cofinality, so there is a cofinal copy of $\mathbb N$ inside it.  Different choices of cofinal copies of $\mathbb N$ would give the same ind-object for any reasonable definition of ind-object.  In any event, this discussion is orthogonal to the intent of the question.

Comment: John -- perhaps you can tell us what sort of thing you have in mind for rank 1 bundles?  Here we get some crazy direct limit of Jacobians x Z; I don't know if one can say much more than that.  Of course the direct limit you have in mind fibers over this (by taking the determinant); so let's say we look at bundles with trivial determinant.  This is still probably pretty crazy, but I suppose one can compute things like the cohomology of this ind-stack...

Comment: That said, I suggest doing things like bounding the ramification of the maps $C'\to C$ if you want real control...

Comment: Could the following article be of any use? http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0393044098000308