# Vector bundles over Riemann surfaces of infinite genus

Tags: cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, riemann-surfaces

Has any work been done on the description of (finite rank) holomorphic vector bundles over Riemann surfaces of infinite genus?

Is there a theory of moduli spaces of such objects?

This question is randomly inspired by [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/259961/universal-moduli-space-of-rank-two-vector-bundles-over-a-curve).

Comment: you may see Horst Knörrer's works https://people.math.ethz.ch/~knoerrer/research.html